# Need help with 2 Transistor Current Limiter Circuit in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, current, bjt, spice

I am new to LTSpice. I have attached a picture of my circuit below:

The goal of the circuit is to provide current to the R1 until It is too high. Then the BJT will activate, shutting the FET off.

For some reason, the simulation is not able to finish the entire sweep. Can anyone help me with why?

[image]

Comment: Does it give you an error message?  You're aware that I1 is a *current* source, whose rule of behavior is "deliver the specified current no matter what the voltage is"?  So when M1 turns off I1 will just rise to however many hundreds of volts it needs to be to drive M1 into breakdown.

Comment: Change I1 to V2  then Voltage sweep **.dc V2 0V  24V 0.1V**

Comment: or use this http://tinyurl.com/y4dvgw9g

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't do so many steps on the first pass, 100 steps is overkill. After 61mA this circuit no longer works, and the simulator can't easily find the DC operating point because it has to steadily increase the voltage in I1 becasue the mosfet doesn't want to turn on (like TimWescott said).

If you want to see this for yourself, make it easier for spice to simulate and put a 1e6 resistor across M1 and it will become apparent what is happening. The node between I1 and R3 will reach kV or MegV. Spice's solver has a hard time when simulating very large values and very small circuit values at the same time. The results aren't physical anyway, the components will burn out at after M1 breaksdown, and if you were testing this circuit in real life, I don't think you'd test with a current source that works the the kV range.

Comment: Is 100 steps  really overkill on LTspice ?  Falstad's Sim in a browser can do continuously with > 500 steps on over a dozen plots at the same time.

Comment: Overkill for the simulation, not the application. Falstad is nice toy demonstrator, I prefer engineering tools with solvers that I have control of

Comment: I bet I have far more realism with Falstad controlling ESR, ESL by skill adding than the other ideal one shot solvers. it is based on physics, not Toys.  You have to model the passive parts and output impedances  Does Spice have Transmission lines or Arc gaps? Or predefined variable  active filters or

Comment: And your point is? Both have options to add ESR and ESL, find a better argument.

Comment: Spice has Transmission lines and Arc gaps

Comment: My argument is your assumption is invalid

Comment: What assumption? and what argument, please be specific, it helps to communicate

Comment: That the simulations are a toy. it is the unskilled user that makes it look like this,

Comment: Falstad is for demonstrating, spice is an engineering tool

Comment: Or the uninformed viewer making false assumptions that it is “just a toy”

Comment: Another false assumption

Comment: Both are for both but not equal. Each better in many ways than the other

Comment: The power is knowing how to use each tool to save time, to validate some assumptions or look at parasitic effects on analog equivalent circuits like Lithium battery simulations which can be done easily if you have the modelling skills much faster inFalstad or verifying passive filter Root Locus points with different filter types instantly with a 10th order Bessel filter vs a Cheby filter with a delay line

Comment: The usefulness in any tool is the easy, power and assumptions on the model you make.  My son-in-Law U of T Prof with tenure status agrees. And they have every tool I can’t imagine

Comment: e.g.I designed a bus bar model for a 4kW 200kHz for U of T validation of their design with all the impedances RLC in about 30 minutes with sprectral spurious responses, load regulation etc all in Falstad f domain , it probably took them a few days using Maxwell Software. But I don’t care if you don’t know how to use it, but if anyone likes I can create an open web session

Comment: For demonstrating lines of flux try http://www.falstad.com/vector3dm/ choose a current loop , choose x slice , increase number of particles, and rotate box

Comment: Or test the current limiter on a 1W tungsten bulb with a slider http://tinyurl.com/y4dvgw9g. Tool ? Or toy?